# creating parallax to move image but image mot move

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to move multiple images in different directions but in Firefox it is showing `[object HTMLSpanElement]` and in Chrome it is showing this error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

There is any typo error with any class or there is same mistake in javascript code. If I remove `position: center` from CSS it is showing

> TypeError: f1 is null

```js
var f1 = document.getElementById("f1");
var f2 = document.getElementById("f2");
var f3 = document.getElementById("f3");
var f4 = document.getElementById("f4");
var f5 = document.getElementById("f5");
var f6 = document.getElementById("f6");


function initParallex() {
  f1.style.left = ((window.pageYOffset / 10) - 300) + "px";
  f2.style.left = (window.pageYOffset / 5) + "px";
  f3.style.left = ((window.pageYOffset / 8) + 100) + "px";
  f4.style.left = ((window.pageYOffset / 6) - 200) + "px";
  f4.style.left = (window.pageYOffset / 15) + "px";
  f5.style.left = ((window.pageYOffset / 12) - 300) + "px";
  f6.style.left = (window.pageYOffset / 20) + "px";
  f6.style.left = (window.pageYOffset / 15) + "px";

}
window.addEventListener("scroll", initParallex);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  height: 100000px;
}
#wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(../img/user-profile-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
  position: center;
  background-size: 100% 100vh;
  z-index: 1;
}
#wrapper > span {
  display: block;
  border: solid;
  z-index: 10;
}
#f1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(../img/3.jpg) no-repeat;
  top: -300px;
}
#f2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(../img/1.jpg) no-repeat;
  right: 100px;
}
#f3 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(../img/5.jpg) no-repeat;
  left: 300px;
}
#f4 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(../img/3.jpg) no-repeat;
  left: -300px;
}
#f5 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(../img/1.jpg) no-repeat;
  left: 300px;
}
#f6 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(../img/5.jpg) no-repeat;
  right: -300px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Parallex 1</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css" />
  <script src="./js/custom.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <span id="f1"></span>
    <span id="f2"></span>
    <span id="f3"></span>
    <span id="f4"></span>
    <span id="f5"></span>
    <span id="f6"></span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your question correctly. It was an absolute train wreck.

Comment: Can you please share this in fiddle.